# cannot reference game before super constructor has been called

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super

So I have a super class Ghost where in the constructor there is a parameter from another class Pacman. Now for the purpose of creating 4 different types of ghosts(randy, silly, tracy and sue if you are into pacman) which have a lot of similarities I am making a subclasses of Ghost. There in the constructor I get the error from the title. 

Some code of Ghost.class:

```
public class Ghost extends Actor
{
    protected Pacman game;
    Randy randy;
    Ghost pinky;    //totally unsure, but not a matter of question
    public Ghost(Pacman game)
    {
        this.game = game;
```

Here is the subclass for Randy:

```
private class Randy extends Ghost {

   Actor randy;

   public Randy(){
       super(game); //here is the error
       randy = new Actor();
       this.game = game;
```

Here is why I am doing it:

```
public void act()
    {
        if (pinky instanceof Randy){
            moveRandom();     // Randy must move ONLY randomly unlike the other ghosts
    } 

    setSlowDown(2);

    code left out here
```

**Note** The code is fragmented. 

 Lastly, I ask the question, because I haven`t found a solution for a dynamic variable. All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Why are you storing instances of each class within itself? Shouldn't the instances of Randy and the other Ghosts be class fields in your Pacman game class? And why do you need to pass a Pacman instance to create your Actors in the first place?

Comment: Why does your `Ghost` class have instance variables `randy` and `pinky`, both of type `Ghost` or a subtype?  This doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Can you show us the `Actor` constructor as well? Also what is a `Pacman`?  Does a `Ghost` need to hold a reference to a `Pacman`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, when I consider this now. Over the Actor class it is from JGameGrid library. And yes I think it must hold such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would get rid of the double-definition of Randy.  "Randy" is used as a member of `Ghost` and also used as a type.  If "Randy" is a type of Ghost (every Randy is a Ghost), make `Ghost` abstract and use a sub-class.  If "Randy" is a "MovementStrategy" then make a new `MovementStrategy` interface and a `Randy` implementation of it (and then set that internally within the `Ghost`.

At no time should one Ghost have two or more movement strategies; because, then a Ghost has a movement strategy it isn't using, which is Cruft and completely undesirable.

This will also prevent the need to do "instanceof" to control you logic, which you really shouldn't be doing for a number of reasons.  If the `MovementStrategy` returns a "next direction", then rely on polymorphisim to have the "Randy" instance return the next direction.  "Instanceof" is a good indication that you are putting code related to a data type outside of the data type, which is anti-ObjectOriented programming.

In general it is better to work with a language's design choices instead of against the language's design choices, so don't immediately embrace non-object oriented techniques within Java until there is a *very* **very** compelling reason to do so.

--- edited to show some code as an illustration ---

```
public Ghost extends Actor {

  private Game game;

  private MovementStrategy strategy;

  private Location location;

  public Ghost(Game game, MovementStrategy strategy) {
    this.game = game;
    this.movementStrategy = strategy;
  }

  // From Actor, I guess
  @Override
  public void act() {
    if (location == null) {
      location = game.addGhost(this);
    }
    move(movementStrategy.getDirection(game, location));
  }

  private void move(Direction direction) {
    location = game.move(this, direction);
  }

}

public interface MovementStrategy {

  public Direction getDirection(Game game, Location location);

}

public class Randy implements MovementStrategy {

  public Direction getDirection(Game game, Location location) {
    return selectRandom(game.getPermittedDirections());
  }

}

// constructing a Ghost with a Randy movement strategy

Game game = new Game();
Ghost ghost = new Ghost(game, new Randy());
```

Comment: Added some code to illustrate the point.  The code isn't perfect, but it's a starting point.

Comment: `If "Randy" is a type of Ghost (every Randy is a Ghost)` this is exactly what I am trying to create.

Comment: "Randy" is a type of movement strategy here, assuming that the only difference between your ghost types is the way they move. If that is not true, then you could still subclass your specific ghosts and override the relevant methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass game as a parameter to the constructor of `Randy`.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? You cannot invoke the super constructor with 'game' when game was not itself passed to your subclass constructor.

Comment: That's not the only problem.  If you *did* pass it in, what would happen if you were to instantiate that `Randy` class?

Comment: @Makoto Huh? What do you mean "what would happen"? You would just do `new Randy(game)` ... and a new instance would get created.

Comment: It doesn't feel like this problem is that simple, though.  There's likely more to it.

Comment: @user4425098 Stack overflow is a different problem. Ask another question, perhaps? Show enough code to reproduce and the traceback of actual exception you are getting.